# Change Logo on incoming external email

Tags: lotus-notes

I have had a request to add a new image to incoming emails if they come from a specific site. I have found a field, among others, that only exists on incoming emails from outside the company. What I have tried is to reference this field in the Logo field of the Memo form. I have an image resource and am trying to do an @Contains on this field within the existing function but it just doesn’t want to replace the users default image with the one I want to use. Has anyone tried this type of thing and if so, what am I missing?

```
@If( @Contains(X_Sender; "postmaster@XXX.com"); "StdNotesLtr35"; 
    @If(@IsNewDoc; @If(@GetProfileField("CalendarProfile";"DefaultLogo")= "";"stdNotesLtr25";@GetProfileField("CalendarProfile";"DefaultLogo"))
    ; @Contains(From; "@"); "StdNotesLtrGateway"; Logo))
```

I added an Image Resource with the alias of "StdNotesLtr35" but no matter what I try it is not appearing on these emails.

Comment: Please show us your formula for the computation of the image ressource... then we can tell you whats wrong. It is definitively possible to do what you want, did something similar myself multiple times

Comment: I added the current code to my original post

Answer (score 0):

I have no Idea where "X_Sender" as a field comes from. It is definitively not default Notes/Domino.

Please try:

```
@If( @Contains(From; "postmaster@XXX.com"); "StdNotesLtr35"; 
     @IsNewDoc; @If(@GetProfileField("CalendarProfile";"DefaultLogo")="";
        "stdNotesLtr25";@GetProfileField("CalendarProfile";"DefaultLogo")); 
     @Contains(From; "@"); "StdNotesLtrGateway"; Logo)
```

I removed the unneccessary second if and replaced "X_Sender" with "From". That should do...

Comment: The X_Sender comes from Salesforce along with a dozen or more other fields that are seen in the Documents tab of the Properties box. From doesn't work as that is the name of the actual person sending the email. I agree with removing the second @If though.

Comment: The issue is that Salesforce sends the email from the senders email address. I need to distinguish an email from Salesforce from all others sent by the same users. Salesforce adds a set of "X_" fields that contain all sorts of information so I thought if I checked one of those for the specific text it would reset the logo. So far it isn't doing that.

Comment: Then what about trying: @If( @IsAvailable( X_Sender ); ...

Comment: Tried that today and still no joy :(   If I had any hair I would be pulling it out about now

Comment: Did you try to find out, if you are at the right place by just entering the formula "StdNotesLtr35" and nothing else? Does the logo change then?

Comment: I have tried that as well. I made the field Computed and the value I want appears in the field value but the image does not change which means there is something else going on  that changes it that I am not aware of. I am stumped

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the formula in the field **Logo**:
[image: Formula in Logo field]

Try to add `@If(@IsAvailable("X_Sender"));"StdNotesLtr35";` right where the arrow points, before the last `Logo`.

Comment: It did not work. Nothing is changing the icon even if the value of the logo field has the value of the image I want to show.